# Transitions on the CSS display property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm currently designing a CSS 'mega dropdown' menu - basically a regular CSS-only dropdown menu, but one that contains different types of content.

At the moment, **it appears that CSS 3 transitions don't apply to the 'display' property**, i.e., you can't do any sort of transition from `display: none` to `display: block` (or any combination).

Is there a way for the second-tier menu from the above example to 'fade in' when someone hovers over one of the top level menu items?

I'm aware that you can use transitions on the `visibility:` property, but I can't think of a way to use that effectively.

I've also tried using height, but that just failed miserably.

I'm also aware that it's trivial to achieve this using JavaScript, but I wanted to challenge myself to use just CSS, and I think I'm coming up a little short.

Comment: Does the CSS transition work if you apply it to the opacity property, rather than display?

Comment: position: absolute; visibility: hidden; is same as display: none;

Comment: @Jawad: Only if you add something like `z-index:0` as well.

Comment: @Jawad: It's recommended to never use `visibility: hidden` unless you _want_ screenreaders to read it (whereas typical browsers won't). It only defines the _visibility_ of the element (like saying `opacity: 0`), and it's still selectable, clickable, and whatever it used to be; it's just not visible.

Comment: @ForestKa that is not 100% true. you can make it non-selectable, -clickable via css: > pointer-events: none; [support is ok](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)

Comment: no support for `pointer-events` in IE 8,9,10, so it's not always ok

Comment: You need to display: none otherwise you'll be stumbling into the hidden object outside the trigger and it'll be showing accidentally... I'm just saying :)

Comment: I find using `visibility: collapse` instead of `visibility: hidden` works

Comment: @ForestKatsch that's not true, at least not anymore. `visibility: hidden` _does_ remove the element from the accessibility tree. [See spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#visibility).

Comment: Using `visibility: hidden` is acceptable for content that doesn't take up space in the normal document flow. Popovers are a good example of elements that can be hidden this way.

Comment: Adding this [link](https://web.dev/learn/css/transitions/) for people in 2022 still struggling to understand transitions and animations.

Comment: See my answer as this is now actually possible in 2023 :)

Comment: For those on SvelteKit, it is [precisely possible](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/in-and-out)

Answer (score 1733, accepted):

You can concatenate two transitions or more, and `visibility` is what comes handy this time.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
div > ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(Don't forget the vendor prefixes to the `transition` property.)

More details are in [this article](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337).

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why do you alter both the visibility AND the opacity? Won't setting the opacity to 0 hide the element - why do you need to set the visibility to hidden too?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo if you set only the opacity, the element is actually still on the page rendering (you can't click thought for example).

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer. It does not deal with the display property and as Rui said, the element still takes up space making it impractical for many situations.

Comment: Note that if you care about accessibility (which you probably do), this answer is actually quite wrong: not using `display:none` means that every focussable/tabindexed element _still exists_ on page and your users will now be tabbing blind through elements that are completely invisible. While this _seems_ to work, it actually makes things worse for a significant-enough part of web users. Instead, you need a two step process, display:none->block and _then_ fade opacity, and in reverse, fade opacity and then display:block->none.

Comment: how to add the same transition as a fade out of the hover?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo You need to delay the visibility transition by the duration of the opacity transition (0.5s in this case): On the `div > ul` selector `transition: opacity 0.5s linear, visibility 0s 0.5s;` and on the `div:hover > ul` selector `transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans While the method you described works, unlike with `opacity: 0;`, elements hidden with `visibility: hidden;` are NOT focusable or tabindexed. So this method is totally fine to use, keeping accessibility in mind.

Comment: he is asking for 'display' not for visibility

Comment: @GMA: Tangential, but `visibility: hidden` can be important on its own from an accessibility perspective. For example, if an element has `visibility: hidden`, it is removed from the accessibility tree, and one does not need an explicit `aria-hidden="true"` attribute for such elements. Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden).

Comment: @RuiMarques for the occupied space problem, in this solution you can add max-height property with the transition, when hover out just set the max-height 0 else set to some high value and then it will not occupy the space.

Comment: I think the reason `display: none` would be preferable is better tab management for accessibility. In a nutshell: with element removed from layout you can't tab to it, but if it's just invisible you get phantom tabbing, which is a pain to manage with JS.

Answer (score 991):

You need to hide the element by other means in order to get this to work.

I accomplished the effect by positioning both `<div>`s absolutely and setting the hidden one to `opacity: 0`.

**If you even toggle the `display` property from `none` to `block`, your transition on other elements will not occur.**

To work around this, always allow the element to be `display: block`, but hide the element by adjusting any of these means:

1. Set the `height` to `0`.
2. Set the `opacity` to `0`.
3. Position the element outside of the frame of another element that has `overflow: hidden`.

There are likely more solutions, but you cannot perform a transition if you toggle the element to `display: none`. For example, you may attempt to try something like this:

```css
div {
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
div.active {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

But that will **not** work. From my experience, I have found this to do nothing.

Because of this, you will always need to keep the element `display: block` - but you could get around it by doing something like this:

```css
div {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for a thorough answer. You're absolutely right about the fact that if the display: property changes at all, then ALL of your transitions will not work. Which is a shame - I wonder what the reasoning behind that is.

On a side note, on the same link I posted in the original question, you can see where I'm at with it. The only (small) problem I have is in Chrome [5.0.375.125] when the page loads, you can see the menu quickly fading away as the elements are loaded on the page. Firefox 4.0b2 and Safari 5.0 are absolutely fine... bug or something I've missed?

Comment: I implemented this, then it didn't work, then I realised that what your saying is this **won't** work. This answer assumes were not all just speed reading the important bits... :)

Comment: This doesn't work because YOU CANNOT TRANSITION HEIGHT FROM `auto`.  It has to be an actual number.

Comment: It's not the height that needs transition its the opacity. @Jez

Answer (score 376):

At the time of this post all major browsers disable CSS transitions if you try to change the `display` property, but CSS animations still work fine so we can use them as a workaround.

**Example Code** (you can apply it to your menu accordingly) [Demo](http://cssdesk.com/7WPCT):

Add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Then apply the `fadeIn` animation to the child on parent hover (and of course set `display: block`):

```css
.parent:hover .child {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

---

## Update 2019 - Method that also supports fading out:

(Some JavaScript code is required)

```js
// We need to keep track of faded in elements so we can apply fade out later in CSS
document.addEventListener('animationstart', function (e) {
  if (e.animationName === 'fade-in') {
      e.target.classList.add('did-fade-in');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('animationend', function (e) {
  if (e.animationName === 'fade-out') {
      e.target.classList.remove('did-fade-in');
   }
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 5px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

div:hover {
    border-color: red;
}

.parent .child {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

.parent:not(:hover) .child.did-fade-in {
  display: block;
  animation: fade-out 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Parent
    <div class="child">
        Child
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The `height: 0` trick (for transitions) mentioned above doesn't seem to work because the height gets set to 0 on the fade-out transition, but this trick seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. But how to fade it out?

Comment: awesome, but when i hover the DIV while the animation runs it flickers (changes opacity to a lower state) ... any idea?

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer doesn't quite make sense. Browsers don't just disable all transitions outright the moment you use the `display` property - there is really no reason to. And even if they *did*, why would animations work then? You can't use the `display` property in CSS animations either.

Comment: Yeah, "change" - I'm not sure why I said "use" there. My point is you can't transition *or* animate `display`, but that doesn't prevent all other properties from animating either so long as you're not transitioning *to* none.

Comment: @BoltClock transitioning to and _from_ none unfortunately: cssdesk.com/rCyBd . It's some kind of implementation limitation.

Comment: CSS desk link is dead!

Comment: You can remove the `-webkit` prefix because [all browsers support animation without it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-animation) nowadays.

Comment: This works perfectly for mouse-over dropdown menus where the height isn't a problem. My dropdown simply fades in on hover of the parent nav item, and fades out when moused-out.

Comment: The fade-out works here but with some js which is sth the OP did not want.

Comment: Thanks, but its weird that the parent size just jumps. I think it should be animated as well.

Answer (score 159):

Instead of callbacks, which don't exist in CSS, we can use `transition-delay` property.

```
#selector {
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide the element content, while height = 0 */
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: height 0ms 400ms, opacity 400ms 0ms;
}
#selector.visible {
    height: 100px; /* any measurable value, not "auto" */
    opacity: 1;
    transition: height 0ms 0ms, opacity 400ms 0ms;
}
```

So, what's going on here?

1. When **.visible** class is added, both `height` and `opacity` start animation without delay (`0ms`), though `height` takes `0ms` to complete animation (equivalent of `display: block`) and `opacity` takes `400ms`.
2. When **.visible** class is removed, `opacity` starts animation (`0ms` delay, `400ms` duration), and `height` waits `400ms` and only then instantly (`0ms`) restores the initial value (equivalent of `display: none` in the animation callback).

Note, this approach is better than ones using `visibility`. In such cases, the element still occupies the space on the page, and it's not always suitable.

For more examples please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@joethedave/achieving-ui-animations-with-react-the-right-way-562fa8a91935).

Comment: It only works with `height:100%` which can destroy the layout in some cases. Great solution, if that's not a problem. One of the few bidirectional working ones.

Comment: You have to set a height - setting `height: auto` makes it disappear instantly.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno why this has so many upvotes, it's totally broken because `height` can't transition.

Comment: height can't transition to auto but max-height can transition to an absurd value.

Answer (score 121):

I suspect that the *reason* that transitions are disabled if `display` is changed is because of what display actually does. It does *not* change anything that could conceivably be smoothly animated.

`display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;` are two *entirely* different things.
Both do have the effect of making the element invisible, but with `visibility: hidden;` it’s still rendered in the layout, but just not *visibly* so.
The hidden element still takes up space, and is still rendered inline or as a block or block-inline or table or whatever the `display` element tells it to render as, and takes up space accordingly.
Other elements do *not* automatically move to occupy that space. The hidden element just doesn’t render its actual pixels to the output.

`display: none` on the other hand actually *prevents* the element from rendering *entirely*.
It does not take up *any* layout space.
Other elements that would’ve occupied some or all of the space taken up by this element now adjust to occupy that space, as if the element simply *did not exist at all*.

`display` is not just another visual attribute.
It establishes the entire rendering mode of the element, such as whether it’s a `block`, `inline`, `inline-block`, `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, `list-item`, or whatever!
Each of those have very different layout ramifications, and there would be no reasonable way to animate or smoothly transition them (try to imagine a smooth transition from `block` to `inline` or vice-versa, for instance!).

This is why transitions are disabled if display changes (even if the change is to or from `none` — `none` isn’t merely invisibility, it’s its own element rendering mode that means no rendering at all!).

Comment: This is correct. It's not immediately obvious, but once you do think about it, it doesn't take long for you to realize that transitioning the `display` property couldn't possibly *work*.

Comment: As good as the above solutions might be, it was very satisfying to get a sensible explanation as for why transitions don't apply to display attributes.

Comment: I disagree. It could make complete sense. If display:none to display:block occurred instantly at the start of the transition, that would be great. And for transitioning back, if it went from display:block to display:none right at the end of the transition, that would be perfect.

Comment: What would be useful would be if transitions supported instant changes for things like `display`, but could still use the delay property so the change happened after a certain period of time.

Comment: I get your logic. On the other hand, it should be possible to transition between an element taking no space (0), to it taking its default space (auto).

Answer (score 66):

I found better way for this issue, you can use CSS Animation and make your awesome effect for showing items.

```
.item {
     display: none;
}

.item:hover {
     display: block;
     animation: fade_in_show 0.5s
}

@keyframes fade_in_show {
     0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: scale(0)
     }

     100% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1)
     }
}
```

Comment: too bad it doesn't work for fading out

Answer (score 61):

`display` is not one of the properties that transition works upon.

See *[Animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)* for the list of CSS properties that can have transitions applied to them. See *[CSS Values and Units Module Level 4, Combining Values: Interpolation, Addition, and Accumulation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#combining-values)* for how they are interpolated.

Up to CSS 3 was listed in *[9.1. Properties from CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-css-transitions-1-20171130/#animatable-css)* (just close the warning popup)

> I've also tried using height, but that just failed miserably.

Last time I had to do this, I used `max-height` instead, which is an animatable property (although it was a bit of a hack, it did work), but beware that it may be very janky for complex pages or users with low-end mobile devices.

Answer (score 40):

You can add a custom animation to the block property now.

```css
@keyframes showNav {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
.subnav-is-opened .main-nav__secondary-nav {
  display: block;
  animation: showNav 250ms ease-in-out both;
}
```

[Demo](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/)

In this demo the sub-menu changes from `display:none` to `display:block` and still manages to fade.

Comment: Unless I am missing something the "demo" link no longer shows a sub-menu transition.

Answer (score 38):

Fade it in with [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

```js
const SECONDS = 1000

setTimeout(() => {
  const item = document.querySelector('.item')
  item.classList.add('shown')
}, 1 * SECONDS)
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}

.item.shown {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
      opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

According to [W3C Working Draft 19 November 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties) `display` is not an *animatable property*. Fortunately, `visibility` is animatable. You may chain its transition with a transition of opacity ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feklee/6UkVH/)):

- HTML:

  ```
  <a href="http://example.com" id="foo">Foo</a>
  <button id="hide-button">Hide</button>
  <button id="show-button">Show</button>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  #foo {
      transition-property: visibility, opacity;
      transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
  }

  #foo.hidden {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition-property: opacity, visibility;
      transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
      transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
  }
  ```
- JavaScript for testing:

  ```
  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

  document.getElementById('hide-button').onclick = function () {
      foo.className = 'hidden';
  };

  document.getElementById('show-button').onclick = function () {
      foo.className = '';
  };
  ```

Note that if you just make the link transparent, without setting `visibility: hidden`, then it would stay clickable.

Answer (score 23):

Edit: display none is not being applied in this example.

```
@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

What's happening above is that through 99% of the animation display is set to block while the opacity fades out. In the last moment display property is set to none.

And the most important bit is to retain the last frame after the animation ends using animation-fill-mode: forwards

```
.hide {
   animation: hide 1s linear;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Here are two examples: https://jsfiddle.net/qwnz9tqg/3/

Comment: You can replace the `display:block` with `position:initial;top:initial;` and `display:none` with `position:fixed;top:-1000vh;` and it will work. (Moving it off screen and outside the normal flow with fixed is basically the same as `display:none`.

Comment: it still leaves the block space in the flow, so it's effectively the same as `visibility`; if you do this for two pages that should replace one another, this won't work as the empty space stays

Answer (score 18):

My neat JavaScript trick is **to separate the entire scenario into two different functions**!

To prepare things, one global variable is declared and one event handler is defined:

```
  var tTimeout;
  element.addEventListener("transitionend", afterTransition, true);//firefox
  element.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", afterTransition, true);//chrome
```

Then, when hiding element, I use something like this:

```
function hide(){
  element.style.opacity = 0;
}

function afterTransition(){
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

For reappearing the element, I am doing something like this:

```
function show(){
  element.style.display = 'block';
  tTimeout = setTimeout(timeoutShow, 100);
}

function timeoutShow(){
  element.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

It works, so far!

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this today, with a `position: fixed` modal that I was reusing. I couldn't keep it `display: none` and then animate it, as it just jumped into appearance, and and `z-index` (negative values, etc) did weird things as well.

I was also using a `height: 0` to `height: 100%`, but it only worked when the modal appeared. This is the same as if you used `left: -100%` or something.

Then it struck me that there was a simple answer. Et voila:

**First,** your hidden modal. Notice the `height` is `0`, and check out the `height` declaration in transitions... it has a `500ms`, *which is longer than my `opacity` transition*. Remember, this affects the out-going fade-out transition: returning the modal to its default state.

```
#modal-overlay {
    background: #999;
    background: rgba(33,33,33,.2);
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: height 0s 500ms, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: height 0s 500ms, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: height 0s 500ms, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: height 0s 500ms, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
        transition: height 0s 500ms, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

**Second,** your visible modal. Say you're setting a `.modal-active` to the `body`. Now the `height` is `100%`, and my transition has also changed. I want the `height` to be instantly changed, and the `opacity` to take `300ms`.

```
.modal-active #modal-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 90000;
    -webkit-transition: height 0s, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: height 0s, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: height 0s, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: height 0s, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
            transition: height 0s, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

That's it, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 12):

Taking from a few of these answers and some suggestions elsewhere, the following works great for hover menus (I'm using this with [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) 3, specifically):

```css
nav .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: max-height 500ms, opacity 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms, opacity 300ms;
}
nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: max-height 0, opacity 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0, opacity 300ms;
}
```

You could also use `height` in place of `max-height` if you specify both values since `height:auto` is not allowed with `transition`s. The hover value of `max-height` needs to be greater than the `height` of the menu can possibly be.

Answer (score 11):

It is as simple as the following :)

```
@keyframes fadeout {
    0% { opacity: 1; height: auto; }
    90% { opacity: 0; height: auto; }
    100% { opacity: 0; height: 0;
}
animation: fadeout linear 0.5s 1 normal forwards !important;
```

Get it to fade away, and then make it `height 0;`. Also make sure to use forwards so that it stays in the final state.

Answer (score 10):

I've came across this issue multiple times and now simply went with:

```
.block {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease;
}

.block--invisible {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

By adding the class `block--invisible` the whole Elements will not be clickable but all Elements behind it will be because of the `pointer-events:none` which is supported by all major browsers (no IE < 11).

Answer (score 8):

Change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:visible`. It works better. I use like this:

```css
#menu ul li ul {
    background-color:#fe1c1c;
    width:85px;
    height:0px;
    opacity:0;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 10px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.6s ease;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul  {
    overflow:visible;
    opacity:1;
    height:140px;
}
```

`visible` is better because `overflow:hidden` act exactly like a `display:none`.

Answer (score 8):

Well another way to apply transition in this situation **without using keyframes** is to set the **width** of your element to **zero** and then unset it on hover

```
.className{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
  width:0;
}

.className:hover{
  visibility:visible;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  opacity: 1;
  width:unset;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a solution for me, by combining `opacity` with `position absolute` (not to occupy space when hidden).

```
.toggle {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
}

.parent:hover .toggle {
  opacity: 1;
  position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate all the answers. Here is what I'm using for similar purposes: transition vs animation.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/grinevri/tcod87Le/22/

```
<div class="animation"></div>
<div class="transition"></div>
```

```
@keyframes animationTo {
  0% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
  100% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
}

@keyframes animationFrom {
  0% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
  100% { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
}

.animation,
.transition{
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.animation{
  animation: animationFrom 250ms;
}

.animation:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: animationTo 250ms;
}

.transition{
  transition: background-color 250ms;
}

.transition:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript is not required, and no outrageously huge max-height is needed. Instead, set your `max-height` on your text elements, and use a font relative unit such as `rem` or `em`. This way, you can set a maximum height larger than your container, while avoiding a delay or "popping" when the menu closes:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav input + ul li { // Notice I set max-height on li, not ul
   max-height: 0;
}

nav input:checked + ul li {
   max-height: 3rem; // A little bigger to allow for text-wrapping - but not outrageous
}
```

See an example here:
http://codepen.io/mindfullsilence/pen/DtzjE

Answer (score 6):

After the accepted answer from Guillermo was written, the CSS
transition specification of 2012-04-03 changed the behavior of the visibility transition and **now it is possible to solve this problem in a shorter way**, without the use of transition-delay:

```
.myclass > div {
                   transition:visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
                   visibility:hidden;  opacity:0
               }
.myclass:hover > div
               {   visibility:visible; opacity:1 }
```

The run time specified for both transitions should usually be
identical (although a slightly longer time for visibility is not a problem).

For a running version, see my blog post *[CSS Transition Visibility](http://www.taccgl.org/blog/css-transition-visibility.html#visibility-opacity)*.

W.r.t. the title of the question *"Transitions on the display: property"* and in response to comments from Rui Marques and josh to the accepted answer:

This solution works in cases **where it is irrelevant if the display or
visibility property is used** (as it probably was the case in this question).

It will not completely remove the element as `display:none`, just make it invisible, but it still stays in the document flow and influences the position of the following elements.

Transitions that completely remove the element similar to `display:none` can be done using height (as indicated by other answers and comments), max-height, or margin-top/bottom, but also see
*[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto/)* and my blog post *[Workarounds for CSS Transitions on the Display and Height Properties](https://www.taccgl.org/blog/css_transition_display.html)*.

In response to comment from GeorgeMillo:
Both properties and both transitions are needed: The opacity property
is used to create a fade-in and fade-out animation and the visibility
property to avoid the element still reacting on mouse
events. Transitions are needed on opacity for the visual effect and on
visibility to delay hiding until the fade-out is finished.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect anyone just starting CSS transitions quickly discovers that they don't work if you're modifying the display property (block/none) at the same time. One workaround that hasn't yet been mentioned is that you can continue to use `display:block/none` to hide/show the element, but set its opacity to 0 so that even when it's `display:block`, it's still invisible.

Then to fade it in, add another CSS class such as "on" which sets the opacity to 1 and defines the transition for opacity. As you may have imagined, you'll have to use JavaScript to add that "on" class to the element, but at least you're still using CSS for the actual transition.

P.S. If you find yourself in a situation where you need to do both `display:block`, and add class "on", at the same time, defer the latter using setTimeout. Otherwise, the browser just sees both things as happening at once and disables the transition.

Answer (score 5):

You can get this to work the natural way you expected - using display - but you have to throttle the browser to get it to work, using either Javascript or as others have suggested a fancy trick with one tag inside another. I don't care for the inner tag as it further complicates CSS and dimensions, so here's the Javascript solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/hweyecu4/17/

Starting with a box like:

```
<div id="box" class="hidden">Lorem</div>
```

A hidden box.

```
div.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#box {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

We're going to use a trick found in a related q/a, checking offsetHeight to throttle the browser instantaneously:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575811/176877

First, a library formalizing the above trick:

```
$.fn.noTrnsn = function () {
    return this.each(function (i, tag) {
        tag.style.transition = 'none';
    });
};
$.fn.resumeTrnsn = function () {
    return this.each(function (i, tag) {
        tag.offsetHeight;    
        tag.style.transition = null;
    });
};
```

Next, we're going to use it to reveal a box, and fade it in:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var tag = $('#box');
    if (tag.hasClass('hidden'))
        tag.noTrnsn().removeClass('hidden')
        .css({ opacity: 0 })
        .resumeTrnsn().css({ opacity: 1 });
    else
        tag.css({ opacity: 0 });
});
```

This fades the box in and out. So, `.noTrnsn()` turns off transitions, then we remove the `hidden` class, which flips `display` from `none` to its default, `block`. We then set opacity to 0 to get ready for fading in. Now that we've set the stage, we turn transitions back on, with `.resumeTrnsn()`. And finally, kick off the transition by setting opacity to 1.

Without the library, both the change to display and the change to opacity would've gotten us undesirable results. If we simply removed the library calls, we'd get no transitions at all.

Note that the above does not set display to none again at the end of the fadeout animation. We can get fancier though. Let's do so with one that fades in and grows in height from 0.

### Fancy!

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/hweyecu4/22/

```
#box {
    transition: height 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

We're now transitioning both height and opacity. Note that we are not setting height, which means it is the default, `auto`. Conventionally this cannot be transitioned - moving from auto to a pixel value (like 0) will get you no transition. We're going to work around that with the library, and one more library method:

```
$.fn.wait = function (time, fn) {
    if (time)
        this.delay(time);
    if (!fn)
        return this;

    var _this = this;
    return this.queue(function (n) {
        fn.call(_this);
        n();
    });
};
```

This is a convenience method that lets us participate in jQuery's existing fx/animation queue, without requiring any of the animation framework that's now excluded in jQuery 3.x. I'm not going to explain how jQuery works, but suffice to say, the `.queue()` and `.stop()` plumbing that jQuery provides help us prevent our animations from stepping on each other.

Let's animate the slide down effect.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var tag = $('#box');
    if (tag.hasClass('hidden')) {
        // Open it
        // Measure it
        tag.stop().noTrnsn().removeClass('hidden').css({
            opacity: 0, height: 'auto'
        });
        var h = tag.height();
        tag.css({ height: 0 }).resumeTrnsn()
        // Animate it
        .css({ opacity: 1, height: h })
        .wait(1000, function() {
            tag.css({ height: 'auto' });
        });
    } else {
        // Close it
        // Measure it
        var h = tag.noTrnsn().height();
        tag.stop().css({ height: h })
        .resumeTrnsn()
        // Animate it
        .css({ opacity: 0, height: 0 })
        .wait(1000, function() {
            tag.addClass('hidden');
        });
    }
});
```

This code begins by checking on `#box` and whether it's currently hidden, by checking on its class. But it accomplishes more using the `wait()` library call, by adding the `hidden` class at the end of the slideout/fade animation, which you'd expect to find if it is in fact hidden - something the above simpler example could not do. This happens to also enable display/hiding the element over and over, which was a bug in the previous example, because the hidden class was never restored.

You can also see CSS and class changes being called after `.noTrnsn()` to generally set the stage for animations, including taking measurements, like measuring what will be the final height of `#box` without showing that to the user, before calling `.resumeTrnsn()`, and animating it from that fully-set stage to its goal CSS values.

## Old Answer

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/hweyecu4/1/

You can have it transition on click with:

```
function toggleTransition() {
  var el = $("div.box1");

  if (el.length) {
    el[0].className = "box";
    el.stop().css({maxWidth: 10000}).animate({maxWidth: 10001}, 2000, function() {
        el[0].className = "box hidden";
    });
  } else {
    el = $("div.box");
    el[0].className = "box";
    el.stop().css({maxWidth: 10001}).animate({maxWidth: 10000}, 50, function() {
        el[0].className = "box box1";
    });
  }

  return el;
}

someTag.click(toggleTransition);
```

The CSS is what you'd guess:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.2);
    transform: scale(.2);
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
    transition: transform 2s;
}
.box1{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

The key is throttling the display property. By removing the hidden class and then waiting 50 ms, *then* starting the transition via the added class, we get it to appear and then expand like we wanted, instead of it just blipping onto the screen without any animation. Similar occurs going the other way, except we wait till the animation is over before applying hidden.

Note: I'm abusing `.animate(maxWidth)` here to avoid `setTimeout` race conditions. `setTimeout` is quick to introduce hidden bugs when you or someone else picks up code unaware of it. `.animate()` can easily be killed with `.stop()`. I'm just using it to put a 50 ms or 2000 ms delay on the standard fx queue where it's easy to find/resolve by other coders building on top of this.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest universal solution to the problem is: feel free to specify `display:none` in your CSS, however you will have change it to `block` (or whatever else) using JavaScript, and then you'll also have to add a class to your element in question that actually does the transition *with setTimeout()*. That's all.

I.e.:

```
<style>
    #el {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #el.auto-fade-in {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 1s ease-out; /* Future, future, please come sooner! */
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    }
</style>

<div id=el>Well, well, well</div>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('el');
    el.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () { el.className = 'auto-fade-in' }, 0);
</script>
```

This was tested in the latest sane browsers. Obviously it shouldn't work in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think SalmanPK has the closest answer. It does fade an item in or out, with the following CSS animations. However, the display property does not animate smoothly, only the opacity.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
      to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

If you want to animate the element moving from display block to display none, I can't see that it is currently possible just with CSS. You have to get the height and use a CSS animation to decrease the height. This is possible with CSS as shown in the example below, but it would be tricky to know the exact height values you need to animate for an element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/v2nup35t/) **example**

#### CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes pushDown {
  0% {
    height: 10em;
  }
  25% {
    height: 7.5em;
  }
  50% {
    height: 5em;
  }
  75% {
    height: 2.5em;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0em;
  }
}

.push-down {
    -webkit-animation: pushDown 2s forwards linear;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");

// Push item down
element.className = element.className + " push-down";
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution has excellent compatibility, and I haven't seen it yet:

```
.hidden-element {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.hidden-element.visible {
  position: static;
  z-index: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Explanation**: it uses the `visibility: hidden` trick (which is compatible with “show-and-animate” in one step), but it uses the combination `position: absolute; z-index: -1; pointer-events: none;` to make sure that the hidden container **does not take space** and **does not answer to user interactions**.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with transition events, so you build two CSS classes for the transition, one holding the animation other, holding the display none state. And you switch them after the animation is ended? In my case I can display the divs again if I press a button, and remove both classes.

Try the snippet below...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Assign transition event
  $("table").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", ".visibility_switch_off", function(event) {
    // We check if this is the same animation we want
    if (event.originalEvent.animationName == "col_hide_anim") {
      // After the animation we assign this new class that basically hides the elements.
      $(this).addClass("animation-helper-display-none");
    }

  });

  $("button").click(function(event) {

    $("table tr .hide-col").toggleClass(function() {
      // We switch the animation class in a toggle fashion...
      // and we know in that after the animation end, there
      // is will the animation-helper-display-none extra
      // class, that we nee to remove, when we want to
      // show the elements again, depending on the toggle
      // state, so we create a relation between them.
      if ($(this).is(".animation-helper-display-none")) {
        // I'm toggling and there is already the above class, then
        // what we want it to show the elements , so we remove
        // both classes...
        return "visibility_switch_off animation-helper-display-none";
      }
      else {
        // Here we just want to hide the elements, so we just
        // add the animation class, the other will be added
        // later be the animationend event...
        return "visibility_switch_off";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table th {
  background-color: grey;
}

table td {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.animation-helper-display-none {
  display: none;
}

table tr .visibility_switch_off {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: col_hide_anim;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes col_hide_anim {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes col_hide_anim {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-o-keyframes col_hide_anim {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes col_hide_anim {
  0%   {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <theader>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th class='hide-col'>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </theader>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class='hide-col'>Age</td>
      <td>Country</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Switch - Hide Age column with fadeout animation and display none after</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I started an open source skeleton project called [Toggle Display Animate](https://github.com/marcnewton/Toggle-Display-Animate).

This skeleton helper will allow you to easily mimic jQuery show/hide, but with in/out CSS 3 transition animations.

It uses class toggles so you can use any CSS methods you want on elements besides display:none|block|table|inline, etc. as well as other alternate uses that can be thought up.

Its main design purpose is for element toggle states, and it supports a revert state where hiding the object allows you to run your keyframe in reverse or play an alternate animation for hiding the element.

Most of the markup for the concept I am working on is CSS, and there is very little JavaScript actually used.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue that I couldn't find the answer to. A few Google searches later led me here. Considering I didn't find the simple answer I was hoping for, I stumbled upon a solution that is both elegant and effective.

It turns out the `visibility` CSS property has a value `collapse` which is generally used for table items. However, if used on any other elements it effectively renders them as *hidden*, pretty much the same as `display: hidden` but with the added ability that the element doesn't take up any space and you can still animate the element in question.

Below is a simple example of this in action.

```js
function toggleVisibility() {
  let exampleElement = document.querySelector('span');
  if (exampleElement.classList.contains('visible')) {
    return;
  }
  exampleElement.innerHTML = 'I will not take up space!';
  exampleElement.classList.toggle('hidden');
  exampleElement.classList.toggle('visible');
  setTimeout(() => {
    exampleElement.classList.toggle('visible');
    exampleElement.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button onclick="toggleVisibility()">Click Me!</button>
  <span class="hidden"></span>
  <span>I will get pushed back up...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `display` you could store the element 'off-screen' until you needed it, and then set its position to where you want it and transform it at the same time. This brings up a whole host of other design issues though, so your mileage may vary.

You probably wouldn't want to use `display` anyway, as you'd want the content to be accessible to screen readers, which for the most part try to obey rules for visibility - i.e., if it shouldn't be visible to the eye, it won't show up as content to the agent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery to set your classes, this will work 100%:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var container = $('.container');
    
    if (!container.hasClass('active')) {
      container.addClass('show').outerWidth();
      container.addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      container.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
        container.removeClass('show');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.container.show {
  display: flex;
}
 
.container.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Toggle</button>

<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Of course you could just use jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` functions, but the advantage of setting classes instead is in case you want to transition to a display value other than `block` (as is the default with `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`).

Here I am transitioning to display `flex` with a nice fade effect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the Jquery [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle) function to manage the visibility of the element, so instead of handling the transition with css I used to [slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) to manage the visibility and to handle the transition part too.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    width: 400px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="toggle-button">Toggle</button>
<button id="slide-toggle-button">Slide Toggle</button>
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>
 
<script>
$( "#toggle-button" ).click(function() {
   $( "p" ).toggle();
});
$( "#slide-toggle-button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best solution, overall, to be: *use a negative top margin instead of* `display:none`.

The solution that worked well for me was to use a negative top margin - margin being valid for animation/transition - to shift the menu off the top of the page after my `transform` transition.  One of the issues for me was that it was taking up space even after being hidden using `visibility`, and this solution below (combined with absolute positioning) solved that problem.  Doing this (and setting visibility to `hidden` for semantic purposes) is almost as good as giving it `display:none`.  Note, however, that the visibility setting below is *optional*, and the real work is being done by the negative margin.

I like this solution because it avoids JavaScript - you can see I'm using an `input` element (hidden underneath a burger icon) to hide/unhide the menu which slides in from the left of the screen.  The one slight annoyance is having to use an "arbitrarily large number" for the negative margin, but it works well enough.  The only fully clean solution IMHO is for transitions to support things like `display` where the transition just waits for the delay then transitions instantly, but with the current CSS standards spec here is my best solution:

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    /* Hide menu */
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: -99999px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);

    transition: margin 0s 0.5s, padding 0s 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}
#menuToggle input:checked~#menu {
    /* Display menu */
    overflow: unset;

    margin: -80px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 125px 50px 25px 50px;
    visibility: unset;
    transform: none;

    transition: margin 0s 0s, padding 0s 0s, visibility 0s 0s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBurgerMenu" />
    <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"">Link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Example of "hiding" an item within a flex box with a transition without using the display property

As others mention it is not possible to trigger a transition on an element you just changed from display: none; to display: block; but you can achieve the same effect using `overflow: hidden`

This answer uses what I learnt from Jim Jeffers answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/7961500

However I wanted to transition on translateX and within a flex container.

To get this working as expected you need to set the following on the item you want to hide and transition.

```
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(150%);
```

Set this css when you want to unhide

```
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
```

And set this to trigger the transition

```
  transform: translateX(0);
```

However you must decouple hiding/showing from triggering the actual transition so that when you hide the element the transition can first be played before you hide it.

Check this example out

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(150%);
}

.sidebar.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebar.expand-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>item1</div>
  <div class='content'>item2</div>
  <div class='content'>item3</div>
  <div class='content'>item4</div>
  <div class='content'>item5</div>
  <div class='sidebar'>side bar withexpandingcontentthattakes up space</div>
</div>

<button onclick="showNav()">Show nav</button>
<button onclick="hideNav()">Hide nav</button>
  <script>
    function showNav() {
      document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.add('expand-content');
      document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.add('show');
    }
    function hideNav() {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.remove('show');
    }
    
    //don't remove the elements space untill the transition has finished
     const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
sidebar.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    if (!sidebar.classList.contains('show')) {
        sidebar.classList.remove('expand-content');
      }
})
    </script>
```

## React tailwind example

```
  const FilterSideBar = (props: Props) => {
      const filterSideBar = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!filterSideBar.current) {
          return
        }
        // Uncomment if we want to change sidebar to hidden by default.
        // filterSideBar.current.classList.add("overflow-hidden", "grow-0", "basis-0", "h-0")
        // filterSideBar.current.classList.remove("ml-6", "min-w-min")
    
        filterSideBar.current.addEventListener("transitionend", (event) => {
          if (!filterSideBar.current || event.target !== filterSideBar.current) {
            return;
          }
          if (filterSideBar.current.classList.contains("translate-x-[150%]")) {
            filterSideBar.current.classList.add("overflow-hidden", "grow-0", "basis-0", "h-0")
            filterSideBar.current.classList.remove("ml-6")
          }
        })
    
        filterSideBar.current.addEventListener("transitionstart", (event) => {
          if (!filterSideBar.current || event.target !== filterSideBar.current) {
            return;
          }
          if (filterSideBar.current.classList.contains("translate-x-0")) {
            filterSideBar.current.classList.remove("overflow-hidden", "grow-0", "basis-0", "h-0")
          }
        })
      }, [])
      return (
        <div
          ref={filterSideBar}
          className={`${props.isOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "translate-x-[150%]"} flex-none transform transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out`}
        > 
            side nav
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2023**

The W3C has made a [addition/change to the spec](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6429) that makes display animatable.

[Starting with Chrome 116](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/entry-exit-animations/) you can use the following

```
.card { animation: fade-out 0.5s forwards; }
@keyframes fade-out { 100% { opacity: 0; display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar like the actual best answer but I use the max-height too, becouse the visibility hidden is not enough sometimes

```js
const paneltrigger = document.querySelector("#paneltrigger")
const panel = document.querySelector("#panel")

paneltrigger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const isOpen = paneltrigger.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "false" ?  false : true;
    
    if(isOpen){
        paneltrigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
        panel.classList.remove('opened')
    }else{
        paneltrigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
        panel.classList.add('opened')
    }
})
```

```css
#panel {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    transition: max-height 1s, visibility 1s, opacity 1s ease
}

#panel.opened {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500000px;
    overflow: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button id="paneltrigger" aria-expanded="false">SHOW / HIDE</button>
<div id="panel">CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the CSS **visibility**: hidden/visible instead of **display** : none/block

```
div {
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

parent:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This reserves the space though, leaving an empty hole. If you want to collapse a space you have to animate height or some other property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
.dropdown {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    opacity: .0;
    color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be handle by using transition timing functions `step-end` and `step-start`

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/y72h8Lky/

```js
$(".run").on("click", function() {
    $(".popup").addClass("show");
});
$(".popup").on("click", function() {
    $(".popup").removeClass("show");
})
```

```css
.popup {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1450;
    background-color: rgba(0, 175, 236, 0.6);
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, top 0.3s step-end;
}
.popup.show {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, top 0.3s step-start;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup"></div>
<button class="run" style="font-size: 24px;">Click on me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get absolute positioning to work properly and all I wanted was to removed the space of the element when it was hidden so I thought I would add my solution to the pool in case someone else is looking for something similar.

In summary what I did was to also transition the height. The key is delaying that transition until after the opacity had completed.

```
.transitionFadeWrapper {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms ease-out, height 0s linear 300ms;
}

.transitionFadeWrapper:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: fit-content;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Maybe something similar can be used to animate the menu in your case. Hope this help.

Comment: why does it have to be linear? second why didnt you just use all

Comment: It doesn't matter cause the animation is immediate but it needs to start the animation after the opacity animation has finished. You cannot use all cause each attribut has different parameters.